# Are higer level weapons better when left behind as a mine

Tags: mod-nation-racers

In Mod nation racers you can pick up item box and upgrade your item by picking up another one. if you hold the fire button you will leave the item behind like a mine.

Does a higher level item leave a better mine? is it bigger or does it delay the racer more when he hits it?

**example**

> you pick up an item box, and you get a rocket. you hold the fire button and leave it as a mine.
>   Later you pick up another item box, you get a rocket again. you pick up another item box so it upgrades, you hold the fire button and it as a mine.

Is the second mine any different then the first mine?
Also do different items have different result(like a shock mine instead of a rocker mine)